# c# split string by ( ' ) apostrophe

Tags: c#, split

I would like to split a string by the `'` in `isn't` so it becomes `'isn', ''', 't';`

```
string input = "the. frog, isn't feeling very well";          

string[] words = input.Split(' ','.','-',',','\'');
```

I'd like to try and keep all the delimiters in place.

Comment: All good ('\'') did the job.

Comment: Could you abbreviate on 'use zero-width look-ahead and look-behind RegExp patterns' I think this is exactly my problem now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the apostrophe in the results, the `String`'s `.Split()` won't do that. It discards the delimiters it finds, giving just the remaining characters in the resulting collection.

To match around the `'` and keep it, you'll have to use RegExp to match in-between characters. This can be done with [look-ahead and look-behind patterns](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) – `(?=pattern)` and `(?<=pattern)`.

```
Regex separators = new Regex(@"(?:[ \.,-]|(?=')|(?<='))");

string[] words = separators.Split(input);
```

> These patterns are considered zero-width, meaning that they don't match characters directly. They instead match an index within the string based on the surrounding characters.
>
> A basic example would be "match 'ab' only when it's followed by 'cd'."
>
> ```
> var pattern = new Regex(@"ab(?=cd)");
> var matches = pattern.Matches("abcd abd abc abtw"); // { "ab" }
> //                             ^^**
> ```

---

On the other hand, if you just want `"isn"` and `"t"` in the results, then you just have to provide an apostrophe in the list of delimiters given to `.Split()`. The literal for that is `'\''`.

```
string[] words = input.Split(' ','.','-',',','\'' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Split()` by passing string arguments

Please see here [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example

```
string str = "hello'world";
string[] newStr = str.Split(new string[] { "'" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Result

```
newStr = ["hello","World"];
```